# Is declaring STL variables in a class definition too revealing?

Tags: interfaces, abstraction

If you are trying to hide implementation, would declaring STL variables be too revealing?

```
// in Word_Bucket.h
class Word_Bucket {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> contents;

    ...etc
}
```

... but then if you wrap it up, to hide the implementation, won't you have to reveal it in the wrapper's interface anyway?

```
// in Word_Bucket.h
class Word_Bucket {
private:
    Bucket contents;

    ...etc
}

// in Bucket.h
class Bucket {
private:
    std::vector<template_stuff> contents;

    ...etc
}
```

Comment: What does any of this have to do with either STL data types or standard library types? The same question applies unaltered if the private data is anything else at all, doesn't it?

Comment: @delnan it seemed to be the simplest example to use; yeah, "std::vector<std::string>" could have been whatever.

Comment: I believe that you should think about what it really means to "hide implementation details", and what you're trying to accomplish by doing so.

"Hiding implementation details" is more about not forcing clients of your code to rely on information that is subject to change than it is to prevent a client from knowing how your code is implemented.

To the other extreme, you could use the ["PIMPL" idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) to totally abstract away the implementation, but that's generally more trouble than it's worth, especially later when you have to debug your own opaque code.

Comment: If a person can merge whatsisname's answer with sbi's answer coherently, that person shall get the check

Answer (score 6):

The point of Information Hiding in OOP **isn't for any purpose of secrecy**. Even without the header files, inspection of your binaries can reveal quite a bit about your internal implementation.

The purpose of Information Hiding is to define the boundaries of the black box for users of a class to interface with, and provides an implicit contract for how your class is expected to behave.

Declaring members public or private isn't to keep them secret, it is to segregate "Here are the controls, don't worry about this other stuff".

If I see a vector in a class declaration as a private member, I'm going to assume that the class manages elements in that vector, and that I don't have to deal with it.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to [whatsisname's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/233841/1512), I do happen to think that information hiding attempts to not to make users of a class aware of its implementation and thus not make assumptions based on the current implementation, because ideally this could change without affecting user code. Given this, C++ is indeed bad at information hiding, because users of a class can see its private parts. (Pun not intentional, but noted.)

As so many things about C++, this is a sacrifice made to performance and backwards compatibility: In order to have stack-based objects, the compiler needs to know the size of those objects at compile-time. Given C's compilation model, this requires the information to be accessible through the class' definition.

You can work around that by either hiding implementations behind polymorphic base classes or by employing the pimple idiom. That will require additional runtime costs, but that's what it takes. Had C++ implemented full information hiding, you would pay for this all the time.

Comment: In a shop where developers have access to the sources for the classes they're using, any security you gain by doing that is [through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).  There's a point where trying to enforce these things through automated means has to give way to making sure your developers are disciplined.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to hide the details of your `contents` implementation, instead of declaring it as a `Bucket`, declare it as a `Bucket*`.  You can proceed as follows:

```
// in Word_Bucket.h
class Bucket; // simple forward declaration of the type allows to use a pointer to it

class Word_Bucket {
private:
    Bucket* contents;
}
```

You'll have to use `new` and `delete` in the constructor and destructor of `Word_Bucket` but using this technique, only `Word_Bucket.cpp` needs to include `Bucket.h`.

Comment: Then you have to doubly declare all your API methods as well, and cause a bunch of hassle for absolutely no benefit.

Comment: The benefits depend on what you objectives are. Also, declaring your method twice is not necessary. Given that your implementation class is "hidden", there's nothing preventing you from declaring its members as "public" and access them directly from the "Word_Bucket" implementation. The "Opaque pointer" technique (also referred to as "Compiler firewall idiom") is used in some cross platform libraries where the developers want to avoid exposing platform-specific details from the public headers.